# SQL: How do I insert data from one table and output to a temporary table with extra value from first table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, migration, temp-tables, insertion

I can use the `OUTPUT` keyword of the insert statement to insert new data to a table and output to a temporary table.

The input table which to be inserted into another table have an Id I need to pass to the temporary table but not the table I going to insert into. This temporary table will later have to use to do extra insertion to the other table.

```
INSERT INTO table1 (Name, Age)
OUTPUT inserted.Id, User.Id (??) INTO TemporaryTable
SELECT Name, Age FROM User
```

Is there a way to do it? Because the next insertion will need the new `table1.Id` with the `User.Id`, so I can migrate some data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the Temporary table you can use Variable so that it will not occupy more memory.

```
create table table1 
(
id int NOT NULL,
,name varchar(50)
,age int,
 PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

insert into table1 (name,age) values ('name', 10)                          

declare @extracolumn as int =  scope_identity() 
select @extracolumn
```

use this @extracolumn in next insert operation.

Answer (score 1):

Have you included the extra column in the schema of the temporary table?

```
create table table1 
(
id int
,name varchar(50)
,age int
)

declare @TemporaryTable table -- or Create table #TemporaryTable
(                             
  id int,                     
  userid int -- defining the extra column                 
);                            

declare @extracolumn as int = 100; 
-- or declare @extracolumn as int = (select value from table where condition)
-- note that subqueries cannot be added directly in the output clause
-- so need to declare and set a variable that holds the value

insert into table1
output  inserted.id,@extracolumn into  @TemporaryTable -- or #TemporaryTable
values(1,'name',10)

select * from @TemporaryTable
```

Output is

```
id  userid
1   100
```